# How to calculate free space in a MySQL datasource deployed dynamically via docker

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-connector

I have a Spring Boot server that's connected to a MySQL server running on a separate docker image. As such I can't do something as simple as a `df` since the image is wired via a URI in the docker configuration and may change in production deployments. E.g. we might switch the DB to use clustering etc.

However, we might run out of space in the DB and need to detect that. Since there's a lot of data we can delete when running out of space this is pretty crucial.

There are a lot of answers related to calculating the amount of space **used** by the DB, that isn't what I want since:

- It's expensive in terms of CPU and I'd like to keep the implementation efficient
- I don't care how much space is taken, only how much is left, I can keep a variable of "total space" and use that to calculate but it would ignore potential increases in the disk size

I found the `data_free` query [here](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,372554,372570#msg-372570), but it seems problematic based on the [following answer](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,372554,372607#msg-372607).

Is there another way to calculate the disk size either via mySQL query or via similar API exposed through spring boot?

Comment: Maybe you can install [UDF](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys) that can exec `df`

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. Not a DBA so this might be completely stupid but how do I make this execute df? I found this for Maria DB https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.3/en/reference/sql-reference/procedural-sql-reference/create-function--udf-.html but the MySQL docs were moved so I'm not sure about the compatibility here.

Comment: very first step is to compile mentioned UDF source into library (file with `.so` extension). Once you copy this `.so` file into your docker image, you need to register it with MariaDB, here is official [example from MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-function-udf/#examples).

Comment: Actually, some instructions on how to register it and execute external program is within [same repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/master/lib_mysqludf_sys.html) : `CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS INT SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';`

Comment: Interesting, will this work on mySQL too? I need to check with admins since this seems like a bit of a security risk. Either way I suggest filing this as an answer. If I don't get a better answer I'll accept this and you'll get the bounty.

Comment: This should work with MySQL too, only thing to keep in mind is that you need to compile UDF library against same version of server you are going to load it into. And yes, this is major security problem - any command can be executed. It might be more secure to modify source code to call [statfs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) directly, so it will only get details of given filesystem instead of executing `df`

Comment: Approach from completely different point of view - create docker volume for your mysql data (usually `/var/lib/mysql`). Make that volume available to your springboot container (in `ro` mode). That will allows you to inspect usage of filesystem directly from java. Assuming both mysql server and springboot app on same docker host.

Comment: @rkosegi wouldn't that limit the ability to scale? The DB could be a cluster on a completely separate set of machines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need this to see the free space within one docker image:

```
docker system df
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/
https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/08/21/cleaning-docker-disk-space-usage/

And it can be run independently of MySQL.  So, I don't see a CPU issue.

Because all the hassles related to MySQL's Data_free and predicting disk usage for an active table, it is not possible to accurately translate free space into the number of rows you can add before running out of space.

If your usage is fairly consistent, run `docker system df` every day (or every hour) and plot the results.  Then guestimate when it will hit zero.  Be pessimistic in drawing the line through the graph.

You say you can "delete data" to free up space.  Be aware that MySQL, in many cases, does *not* return the freed space to the OS (that is, Docker).  Instead it leaves the table fragmented.  That is, `DELETEing` rows leaves room for new `INSERTs` into the *same* table.  (There are variations on this; we can discuss further if you get more specific on "delete data".)

If the data size does not grow/shrink in a "regular" way, do you at least know when to expect "bursts"?  Chew up some CPU in the lull between bursts.

If you can "delete some data" whenever you need to, why not keep the data pruned.  This would spread out the overhead, and (hopefully) keep the space out of trouble.

If you are talking about 'huge' tables, I have several tips on doing [*big deletes efficiently*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

**Plan B**

Docker can reach into the main filesystem for directories.  Put MySQL's data tree there.  Then you are not asking about the space in Docker, but space in the main system.  (I am assuming you have lots more free space there??)

Comment: You're right, deleting won't necessarily reclaim space and byte data isn't easily quantified. But I can define a threshold and reduce the time to live of specific rows that I know would take up space. Packing up the DB is something we can do on the APM side. I have a specific set of blob entries that go into the DB and get deleted after a few days. I can reduce their TTL if the HD is filling up. I thought about using JMX to monitor the DB which would keep the docker layer hidden from the Java source code.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rick. I was looking for a hack but I guess this is pretty much the only way to get this done and I guess you should know!